# Soundmanager 2 not works with angular js "ng-repeat" directive

Tags: angularjs, soundmanager2

i`m busy on a music store web application with JAVA for back-end and Angular JS/HTML5/CSS3 for front-end.
ammm, and for music play back i used [Sound Manager Java Script Library](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), all thing work fine with static 360 player, but when i try to use sound manager in ng-repeat directive, that not works, any suggestion please ? and is sound manager works with live dom elements created by angular js "ng-repeat" ?

**Sound Manager Init**

```
                // init Sound Manager

            soundManager.setup({
              // path to directory containing SM2 SWF
              url: 'player/'
            });

            threeSixtyPlayer.config.scaleFont = (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)?false:true);
            threeSixtyPlayer.config.showHMSTime = true;

            // enable some spectrum stuffs

            threeSixtyPlayer.config.useWaveformData = true;
            threeSixtyPlayer.config.useEQData = true;

            // enable this in SM2 as well, as needed

            if (threeSixtyPlayer.config.useWaveformData) {
              soundManager.flash9Options.useWaveformData = true;
            }
            if (threeSixtyPlayer.config.useEQData) {
              soundManager.flash9Options.useEQData = true;
            }
            if (threeSixtyPlayer.config.usePeakData) {
              soundManager.flash9Options.usePeakData = true;
            }

            if (threeSixtyPlayer.config.useWaveformData || threeSixtyPlayer.flash9Options.useEQData || threeSixtyPlayer.flash9Options.usePeakData) {
              // even if HTML5 supports MP3, prefer flash so the visualization features can be used.
              soundManager.preferFlash = true;
            }
```

**Angular ng-repeat**

```
    <div class="mod-contents">
    <div class="questions-block" ng-repeat="question in filtered = ( questionList | filter:searchKey | orderBy : predicate : reverse)">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 pull-right">
            <div class="thumbnail block-black ">
                <h3 class="block-title rtl-element">{{ question.description }}<span class="text-muted"> ({{ question.cat_code }}) </span></h3>     
                <div class="ui360 ui360-vis player-wrapper-md player-md "><a href="pac_test.mp3"></a></div>                
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: SoundManager is only responsible for handling existing DOM elements. If you're adding new DOM elements after SoundManager has run then it becomes your responsibility.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem.  I think I know why it's happening.  I believe in the javascript for sound manager it looks for instances of a sound manager player and doesn't find any.  The ng-repeat section is not static; it can change.  So when you load the page and the sound manager loads, the ng-repeat section does not yet contain any elements.  Therefore sound manager decides not to add an event handler for checking if you click on the button.

I edited the mp3-player-button.js and in the init section I commented out where it said "if (foundItems>0)"  so that it always adds the sound manager event handler.

This solution is a little hacky - so maybe you can implement something smarter.  But it works for me.  Hope it Helps!

Comment: This is not fault of soundmanager ! it made for static playback ! you can use another player ! i know soundmanager 360 player is so sweet ! anyway , i`m working on sound manager to make it dynamic :)